# Way to detect frozen video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is there a way to detect frozen video with ffmpeg? I only need to know if there are rather large regions of frozen video, say 10 seconds or more.

I'm familar with the [blackdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blackdetect) filter.

Maybe you could first difference adjacent frames, then use blackdetect to tell whether the difference has not changed? I'm not sure how to perform the difference though.

Comment: `tblend=difference` will produce frame differentials.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [freezedetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#freezedetect) filter. It is newer than the 4.1 release branch so use a build from the current git master branch. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Linux, macOS, and Windows.

## Example

```
ffmpeg -i freeze.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=2" -map 0:v:0 -f null -
```

## Options

- `noise` (or `n`): Set noise tolerance. Can be specified in dB (in case "dB" is appended to the specified value) or as a difference ratio between 0 and 1. Default is -60dB, or 0.001.
- `duration` (or `d`): Set freeze duration until notification (default is 2 seconds).

## Example output

Refer to the `lavfi.freezedetect` metadata keys in the console output.

```
ffmpeg version N-93663-ga42e761b96 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.100 / 58. 52.100
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 49.100 /  7. 49.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'freeze.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:28.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 115:87 DAR 1840:783], 1322 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 115:87 DAR 1840:783], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.52.100 wrapped_avframe
[freezedetect @ 0x55f7a55c9800] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 10.01
[freezedetect @ 0x55f7a55c9800] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration: 13.1381x    
[freezedetect @ 0x55f7a55c9800] lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end: 23.1481
frame=  695 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:28.98 bitrate=N/A speed=  40x    
video:364kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

## Outputting the results to a file

You can combine the metadata filter to just get the freeze info:

```
ffmpeg -i freeze.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=2,metadata=mode=print:file=freeze.txt" -map 0:v:0 -f null -
```

Which results in `freeze.txt`:

```
frame:288  pts:288288  pts_time:12.012
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start=10.01
frame:555  pts:555555  pts_time:23.1481
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration=13.1381
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end=23.1481
```

See the [metadata filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#metadata_002c-ametadata) for more options.

Comment: Can we use it with `ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018`?

Comment: @TinaJ Way too old. "freezedetect is newer than the 4.1 release branch so use a build from the current git master branch. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Linux, macOS, and Windows."

Comment: Thanks. Used the file version. My video doesn't have freeze now, but the file has many unnecessary info for each frame: `frame:0    pts:0       pts_time:0
stereo_mode=checkerboard_lr
frame:9    pts:9009    pts_time:0.3003
stereo_mode=checkerboard_lr`

Comment: @TinaJ Can't suggest anything without command and log.

Comment: it's fine. Probably since my video has no frozen frames. Can you please answer my other question as well? I'm trying to create a frozen video sample with ffmpeg:https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/ffmpeg-no-such-filter-error

Comment: Can you pass those into `freezeframes`? My goal is to output those as pngs.

Answer (score 0):

As of a few months ago, there is a `freezedetect` filter: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#freezedetect

Original patch: https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/patch/10988/