# How to detect Intervals of Frozen Videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, video-encoding

I'm trying to detect intervals where a given video is frozen. Looking at a related post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1313070/way-to-detect-frozen-video-with-ffmpeg), apparently `FFmpeg` has a filter named `freezedetect` which exactly does this. But the post had no accepted answer, neither any examples.

How can we use `FFmpeg` for frozen video detection? Any other tool and libraries, as long as free, is also welcome.

Comment: I added [a more detailed answer with examples](https://superuser.com/a/1429300/110524) to the older question.

Comment: @llogan can you please answer my other question as well? I'm trying to create a frozen video sample with ffmpeg! https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/ffmpeg-no-such-filter-error